# port sha-1 hash from C# to Android/java

Tags: java, c#, android, sha1

I need to port the following code from C#

```
    private string hashcode(string code)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(code);
        byte[] inArray = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1").ComputeHash(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
    }
```

to an Android App. I have this in Java:

```
private static String hashCode(String userCode) {
    String hashSha1;
    MessageDigest digest = null;
    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    digest.reset();
    byte[] data = digest.digest(userCode.getBytes());
    return Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Alas, this code does not produce the same results. Finding out why is a pretty wild goose chase.

What can I do in Android to get the same hashes?

Comment: why you need to generate the hash again?

Comment: Huh? What's the point of a hash if you *don't* want to be able to generate it again?

Comment: I simply need to port this code. The code generates the hash(es).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the C# code you've got for converting the `userCode` string to bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(code);
```

And the Java code is just:

```
userCode.getBytes()
```

That means in Java you're using the platform-default encoding, is UTF-8 on Android. You should specify the equivalent encoding to [`Encoding.Unicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode), which is [`StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_16LE).

You should pretty much *never* call either `String(byte[])` or `String.getBytes()` which both use the platform-default encoding. *Always* specify the encoding to use.

On a more general point, you said that "finding out why is a pretty wild goose chase" - but in situations like this, the solution is almost *always* to log in detail one step in the transformation at a time. You have three transformations here:

- `String` to `byte[]` (encoding `userCode` as binary data)
- MD5 hashing (`byte[]` to `byte[]`)
- Encoding the hash as base64

If you had taken each of those steps individually, and logged the results, you'd have spotted that the problem was in the first step.

Answer (score 1):

Android has UTF-8 as default character set. Try [`String.getBytes(Charset charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) using [`StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_16LE) instead.

Comment: Better to specify `UTF_16LE` to be explicit about endianness.